# Android - How to get all file path from internal storage or delete all files from internal storage

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I am in middle of a project where I am storing files in internal storage as follows:

```
try {
     FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + filename);
     file.write(stringData);
     file.flush();
     file.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

After creating the file I can able to delete the file by its name which I am giving when I am creating it as follows:

```
File f = new File("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + fileName);
f.delete();
```

That all is done and working.

> My problem is I want to get all the files which are stored in the internal storage without specifying the name of the files.

**Note: I can get the file by specifying the name one by one.**

> But can I get all the files from internal storage or delete all of them directly without specifying each filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can get File objects for all files in the directory like this:

```
File f = new File("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName());
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File fInDir : files) {
    fInDir.delete();
}
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Comment: Let me check it thomas

Comment: You should probably get the data path using [`context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir)

Comment: Thanks its giving me all files. but i need only the files which i have created not other system generated default files

Comment: Then you are better off keeping a list of files you generated and cleaning them up.